# Trouble Manipulating Custom Text Boxes with Shopify Code

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, shopify

I have a custom box on my site for customers to enter a product customization, on the Shopify platform. The main box (name="properties[Engrave]") appears based on a conditional set of parameters, with no issue. This week, I attempted to add a second box, based on similar parameters (name="properties[Engrave2]"), but it does not seem to function properly. The text restrictions do not apply to the box (name="properties[Engrave2]") and it will only hide when the "No Engravings" option is selected. In a quick summary, I am attempting to get the following 3 processes to function. I have attempted numerous edits of the code, with little success, and would appreciate any help!

1. User selects no engraving: 0 text boxes appear
2. User selects 3 character engraving: 1 text box appears (name="properties[Engrave]") with the 3 character limitation
3. User selects 12 character engraving: 2 text boxes appear (name="properties[Engrave]", name="properties[Engrave2]") with the first (name="properties[Engrave]") having a 3 character limitation and the second (name="properties[Engrave2]") having a 12 character limitation

HTML

```
<p><label for="engrave"><b>Please Engrave:</b></label></p>
<p><input type="text" id="engrave" name="properties[Engrave]" placeholder="Your monogram - 3 character limit..."/></p>
<p><input type="text" id="engrave" name="properties[Engrave2]" placeholder="Your banner message - 12 character limit..." /></p>
```

Corresponding Java

```
var chk = $("[name='properties[Engrave]']", "[name='properties[Engrave2]']").attr('id');
if(variant.option1 == "No Engravings" || variant.option2 == "No Engravings" || variant.option3 == "No Engravings"){
  $("[name='properties[Engrave]']").hide();
    $("#" + chk).val("");  
    $("#" + chk).removeAttr("maxlength");      
    $("#" + chk).parent().siblings("p").hide();
  $("[name='properties[Engrave2]']").hide();
    $("#" + chk).val("");  
    $("#" + chk).removeAttr("maxlength");      
    $("#" + chk).parent().siblings("p").hide();
}

else if(variant.option1 == "3 Characters or Less" || variant.option2 == "3 Characters or Less" || variant.option3 == "3 Characters or Less"){
  $("[name='properties[Engrave]']").show(function(){
    $("#" + chk).val("");
    $("#" + chk).attr("maxlength",3);
    $("#" + chk).parent().siblings("p").show();
  });
  $("[name='properties[Engrave2]']").hide();
    $("#" + chk).val("");  
    $("#" + chk).removeAttr("maxlength");      
    $("#" + chk).parent().siblings("p").hide();
}

else if(variant.option1 == "12 Characters or Less" || variant.option2 == "12 Characters or Less" || variant.option3 == "12 Characters or Less"){ 
  $("[name='properties[Engrave]']").show(function(){
    $("#" + chk).val("");
    $("#" + chk).attr("maxlength",3);
    $("#" + chk).parent().siblings("p").show();
   });  
  $("[name='properties[Engrave2]']").show(function(){
    $("#" + chk).val("");
    $("#" + chk).attr("maxlength",12);
    $("#" + chk).parent().siblings("p").show();
   });            
}
```

Thank you so much, please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Comment: I would like to help , but can you please provide a fiddle , digging around these issues take time , so you better provide fiddle to save your time and mine as well :)

Comment: @ProllyGeek here is a fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/joe847/s5mptqph/

It does not seem to operate as it would on my site (selecting, the dropdowns, etc) Will this do?

Answer (score 0):

i have tested your code, You can check at:  http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/nfrcw03n/

change for try:

```
var variant = {
    option1:'12 Characters or Less',
    option2:'12 Characters or Less',
    option3:'12 Characters or Less',
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately this still does not solve the issue at hand. The three processes listed above still are not functioning and both boxes are not cooperating. I can't figure out why!